# Does Box.net SDK or API supports notification for any changes(add/delete/modification of any file or Folder)

Tags: box-api

Is it possible get notification on application level  on client side in iOS(and Android) whenever some changes happens like new file/folder added or removed on Box.net? Please confirm if SDK supports this behaviour, if not then is there any way to implement this behaviour on client side.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get notifications about events happening in a user's account by using the /events endpoint:

http://developers.box.com/docs/#events

Essentially, you'll need to authenticate as the user via [OAuth2](http://developers.box.com/oauth/) and issue an OPTIONS request to the /events endpoint to get a realtime server URL. You should set up a long poller to poll that realtime server, and when it issues a response that notifications are available, issue an authenticated GET request to /events?stream_type=....

Both the iOS SDK and the Java/Android SDKs should support this.
https://github.com/box/